# What's the meaning of "a definite shadow, if you’ll pardon the paradox, a broken shadow"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Following is a part from the short story *Joanna Silvestri* by Roberto Bolano

> And anyway the photo he has shown me of the man presumed to be English is old and blurry, it shows a young man of twenty-something, and the English I remember was well into his thirties, maybe even over forty, **a definite shadow, if you’ll pardon the paradox, a broken shadow**; I didn’t pay much attention to him, although his features have remained in my memory: blue eyes, prominent cheekbones, full lips, small ears.

What might be the meaning of the part in bold?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I'm a little puzzled by this as well. What has your research shown?

Comment: A fuller context is given [here](https://booksvooks.com/fullbook/the-return-pdf-roberto-bolano.html?page=10), where it is clear that English is a person's name, not nationality.

Comment: The sentence doesn't immediately make a lot of sense to native English speakers, either. It presumably is some kind of metaphor; reading the entire story might help explain it.

Comment: Presumably the paradox is that 'a shadow' usually refers to something indefinite.

Comment: The later sentence *"I met R. P. English on one of my many shoots around Italy, but his face receded into the shadows long ago."* suggests that the speaker means that English is just a shadow in memory, an incomplete one at that.

Comment: I remember my dad once asked me about the meaning of  the lyric in the 1965 hit song by Jonny Mandel and P.F. Webster: *The shadow of your smile / When you are gone / Will color all my dreams / And light the dawn*.

Comment: English was *a shadow of his former self*. He had gone downhill. A *broken shadow* intensifies the metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I discovered is that this work is translated from Spanish. The original phrase [appears](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Llamadas_telef%C3%B3nicas/pMwSDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=sombra) to be:

> ... una sombra definida, valga la paradoja, una sombra derrotada...

With the disclaimer that I'm not fluent in Spanish: *derrotada* appears to be translatable as "defeated" or "beaten." This is indeed a meaning present in the English "broken," but I had imagined that it was saying something about the coherency and consistency of a shadow projected by light.

In addition, although the word *sombra* appears to be a very close direct match to the English "shadow," it also can be a synonym for *fantasma*, as the English "shade" can mean a ghost. This supports the interpretation suggested by rajah9: the intent is to describe the memory of the man as "a shadow"/ghost of his former self, broken/defeated and faded.

The "paradox" is probably what Kate Bunting suggested, that the speaker used *definida* to express certainty (he was "definitely" a shadow), and then comments on the cognitive dissonance as shadows/shades/ghosts (and memories) are indefinite, incoherent, fuzzy, or ill-defined.

Answer (score 0):

This may hint at the expression "A shadow of his former self."

> Someone or something that has changed dramatically to become decreased in vivacity in some way, often following negative circumstances or some traumatic event.
> *Ever since Tim was in that accident, he's been a shadow of his former self.*

Source: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+shadow+of+former+self)

(edit: English is a name, not a nationality; thanks @WeatherVane)

Perhaps the author is expressing that R.P. English lacks vitality, and is a shadow of his former self. The author might be indicating a deep brokenness in the English (which would be paradoxical as shadows are usually unbroken darkness).

Comment: I wondered that too, but the photo is of a younger man than the person she remembers.

Comment: I think "a definite shadow, if you’ll pardon the paradox, a broken shadow" applies to the older person being remembered, not the one in the photograph, although I agree it's ambiguous.